# Can collisions between particles in the canoncial ensemble be represented by a potential?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, collision

The professor in a statistical mechanics class said that in the canonical ensemble, you could represent interaction between particles as a potential in the partition function expression. But how about collisions (assume elastic) between particles. This is an interaction. Can this be represented by a potential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are several mathematical models you can use to describe an elastic collision. One of the most popular is the [hard-sphere potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_spheres) which assumes that the molecules are spheres of radius $a$ that cannot interpenetrate each other. Mathematically, it takes the form

$V(r) = 0$ if $r>2a$

$V(r) = +\infty$ if $r<2a$, $r$ being the distance between the centers of two spheres.

A more realistic, yet more complicated model is the [Lennard-Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) potential. It takes into account two terms : one varying in $1/r^{12}$ that is purely phenomenological and that describes the non-interpenetrability of molecules. The other term in $-1/r^6$, which is attractive, describes the attraction between two neutral molecules due to Van der Waals interactions.